# How to track downloads using php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have simple cakephp site. I want to track the downloads of the files in the `webroot/files` folder.

Is there a way to track it.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question probably needs to be more specific (what do you mean by "track") but to start, I would suggest not serving files directly. Serve the files up using a PHP script and sending the necessary headers for downloading. The links can still be to the files but you can use htaccess and `mod_rewrite` to direct all requests to your PHP script. Then you can use the PHP to track what you need (IP address, download count, whatever). NOTE: you cannot track download progress - just in case that's your intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at CakePHP's [Media views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views). This will allow you to easily serve files using PHP, allowing you to increment a counter in the database when downloads occur.